# IE 11 won't accept any cookies sent from Tomcat on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, cookies

I use code below to send a cookie to browser:

```
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("data", encrypt); 
            cookie.setMaxAge(seconds);                      
          //cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
          //cookie.setDomain("/");
            resp.addCookie(cookie);
```

I use Apache Tomcat as Web Server, version 7.0.70. When running on Windows, IE 11 accepts the cookie, but on Ubuntu, IE 11 rejects the cookie, at least as far as I can see.

Is there any difference between tomcat on these different operating systems? I just need to make IE 11 accept a cookie sent from Tomcat on Ubuntu.

Comment: what is the value of `seconds`

Comment: http is http. the client shouldn't care what server is sending the response, the protocol remains the same.

Comment: @Jens `int seconds = 60;   `

Comment: @Ron can it be that the cockie is outdated if it is recieved by the browser?

Comment: @MarcB  I forget to tell that  Chome and Firefox work. I mean they accept cookie both situations.

Comment: @Jens Chome and Firefox can accept cookie. So the reasean seems to has nothing to do with MaxAge which is 60.

Comment: You might have to use a "version 1 cookie", depending upon the value of `encrypt`. Version 0 cookies ("Netscape Cookies") are more interoperable but have some restrictions on the content of those cookies. Another option would be to encode the value in a way that is "version 0 compatible" -- something like base64.

Comment: I use tomcat 8.5.4，problem solved.